# How to set iOS device model in Google Analytics (Using Cordova)?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-analytics

I am developing an Ionic app for iOS and Android. I use Cordova google-analytics-plugin for Google Analytics. It looks like plugin does not set iOS device model. Model is mentioned as "not set" in Google Analytics. It works fine for Android.

[image: Device info in Google Analytics]

How do I set iOS model correctly (e.g. iPhone 6, iPhone 7, ...)?
Or is there any other plugin that sets iOS model correctly?

Thank you.

---

Update:

Did not find an exact way to do this.
But two possibilities.

1) Get the iPhone model from platform string.
https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models
Create a custom dimension to and set the model.

2) Can find the model by filtering by device resolution.
https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions
Not the perfect way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [cordova device plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html), `device.model` returns the name of the device's model or product

Comment: After getting model using device.model, How do we set it in Google Analytics? I cannot see a method in  google-analytics-plugin to set the device model. :(

Comment: here you can see allowed methods to use https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

Comment: Do I need to use custom dimensions?